# Incapaz de introducir un anuncio de Google dentro de una noticia

Tags: html, google-adsense

Buenas a todos,

Quisiera introducir un anuncio de Google en mitad de una noticia, pero el código no es correcto. No sé si puedo poner el código directamente así que no voy a poner el script, tiene la típica estructura de los anuncios de Google.

Edito para agregar el código:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- anuncios -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-97601142716609XX"
     data-ad-slot="62861274XX"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

El caso es que por la razón que sea el código en el texto se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el creador de nuevos artículos, que es una herramienta que he creado yo mismo, no paso por ningún filtro de `strip_tags()` o `htmlspecialchars()`, puesto que soy el único que publica artículos. Por lo tanto no entiendo por qué me está haciendo eso.

La información del texto la recojo de la siguiente forma:

```
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];
$articulo = a_html($articulo);
$articulo = para_vista_previa($articulo);
```

Donde las dos funciones no es más que para traducir unas etiquetas que tengo agregadas al editor de texto y traducirlo a código html.

¿A qué puede ser debido?

Comment: @AdrianaHernández No sé exactamente a qué te refieres.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández es que no entiendo si te refieres aquí en la pregunta o en el código, aunque no sé cómo puedo llevarlo a formato texto.

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Añadido.

Comment: Bien, esa era la idea, ahora si quieres podemos eliminar todos los comentarios para dejar limpia la pregunta, tu borra los tuyos y yo los mios claro... ya que no se debe hacer un debate por aqui. Yo, lamentablemente no te puedo ayudar porque no conozco del tema, pero intento contribuir en lo que puedo y hasta donde puedo

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he resuelto quitando todos los espacios, si dejaba alguno me incluía un `<br>` y el código no funcionaba.